# No option to change time zone

Tags: macos, time, timezone

So the clocks switched, but my country doesn't use DST. So I'm stuck with the wrong time here, and I can't change it without manually setting the time. I don't want to manually set the time one hour back. There is just no "set" button for the timezone:

[image]

As you can see, it thinks I am in CDT although I'm actually in CST.

The "Set time zone automatically" doesn't work and has no effect. Location services are on and "Setting time zone" is on in the System Services under Location Services. I'm using macOS Ventura 13.2.

How can I switch the timezone, or disable DST?

Comment: Is your 'nearest city' correct? It's likely to be using that as a guide to DST dates.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, but the only options for "Closest city" are US cities.

Comment: Can you not pick by clicking in a map? I can't check any of this, I live in London… which is kind of 'popular' as a time zone, GMT & unix time being based right here ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I think I should be able to, but where is this map?

Comment: Maybe try enable "Set time zone using your current location"? What does it do?

Comment: Oh, maybe you can only get it at initial setup. Have a look in Language & region rather than Date & Time. There's a huge list of pretty small territories around the States.

Comment: @Thinkr Enabling that still uses CDT and just sets the closest city to Birmingham.

Comment: The Region in Language & Region is correct for where I live (I set it when I set this up), so it seems like it should know what to do...

Comment: I remember setting the timezone when setting it up. IIRC, the only option was to set the closest city, so I had no idea and just picked some random one, then fixed it later.

Comment: But do you really live near Birmingham?

Comment: @Thinkr I don't. It's just the closest in terms of longitude, and I can only pick from cities in the US.

Comment: Try this from https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-the-date-and-time-mchlp2996/mac : Manually: Turn off “Set time zone automatically using your current location,” click Set, enter a city in the text field, select the full city name from the list, then click OK.

Comment: Aha, that worked! I didn't realize you could just type anything into the field. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept it. What's strange is that it can't set the time zone itself.

Comment: You can always turn off the automatic time, and increment the hour youself.

Comment: @naffetS I did not see your comment saying that it worked! Glad it did! I have posted it as an answer. :)

Comment: For those on Ventura and later for whom this doesn’t work, just check privacy/security settings that you give system services -> time zone location access. After that, you can select and de-select “set time zone automatically” and revoke access again; it will allow you to pick your time zone from now on. The cause is shoddy logic programming I guess: if you had “auto time zone” set before, and then revoked time zone location access, the prefpane ends up in a state where time zone just cannot be changed in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manually set your time zone

According to [Set the date and time automatically on your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2996/mac#:%7E:text=apple%20menu%20%3E%20system%20settings%2C%20click%20general%20in%20the%20sidebar%2C%20then%20click%20date%20%26%20time),

You can go to *System Settings → General → Date & Time*. Enable the "**Set the time and date automatically**" option, click the "*Set*" button, and then enter the city where you live in the text box.. Select the full city name from the list and click on "*OK*".

At last, don't forget to turn on “**Set time zone automatically using your current location**”.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has already been answered but it didn't work for me. [This answer from Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254633043?answerId=258650681022#258650681022) is what worked for me.
Here is a breakdown of the answer:
For this question, we'll be using the terminal.

1. In your terminal, use the below command to find out the  timezones that are available. Go through the different timezones and find yours

```
sudo systemsetup -listtimezones | more
```

[image: list of timezones on Mac]

2. Next, set your timezone to the one you want. In this example, I'll be setting the timezone to `Africa/Abidjan`

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone Africa/Abidjan
```

3. Verify that you have set the timezone correctly

```
sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
```

Comment: After doing this, how do you undo it so that MacOS sets it automatically again? :P

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It will continue to do this automatically. I'm currently on macOS Ventura 13.3.1, and there's an option to "Set time zone automatically using your current location". Months after writing the answer above, I read that you can type your city in the 'Closest City' dropdown. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

After trying and trying, it was very simple to change time zone manually in Ventura: just typing the city name directly on the "closest city" dropdown menu.

Comment: The OP says that there is no nearest city in the same timezone

Comment: @mmmmmm OP literally said that typing in the city name worked. It's just the drop down that doesn't have a city in their timezone.

Comment: I was plugged into the internet via ethernet. When I unplugged, connected via wifi, toggled both "set time and date auto.." and "set time zone auto..". The time zone was corrected automatically

Comment: This worked for me. The dropdown box didn't suggest you could type anything. Only cities form India were listed here while I live in Europe.